# How to get a count of all projects using code analysis

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I think I’ve run into a bit of a tricky problem to solve. I need to get a count of our projects that are using code analysis. This is what I've done so far:

1. First, I installed [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/). That’s a lightweight grep utility
   for Windows.
2. Then I ran AstroGrep and pointed to my local C:\DevTfs2010\Apps. It
   appears that 272 out of 354 .csproj files have this text:
   `<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>` The problem  with this
   approach is that I’m only running this against what *I* have on *my*
   laptop. There is much more in TFS.
3. So I remoted into the build server because I thought I could just
   run AstroGrep there. The problem with this approach is that I would
   be counting the same projects many times; one for the Main branch
   and another for each version that has been released.

How can I get a count of projects using code analysis without including all of the released versions?

Answer (score 0):

I'll share how I was able to make this work. If anyone has a better way, please share.

On our build server, run [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/) to search the .csproj files for code analysis being set to true.

[image]

Copy to Excel and use a formula to display a 1 if the path contains “main.”

Note: The reason I used "main" is because all of our main trunks have the word "main" in the folder structure. This eliminates counting all the release versions.

Formula: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("main",A1)), 1, 0)

[image]

Count the total for Core and for Apps (our two main team projects), and there’s your number.